# Upgrading Rho Application to Jquery mobile 1.4.5 from 1.3.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, rhomobile

I am trying to upgrade Jquery mobile from 1.3.0 to 1.4.5 for my Rho Application.

it works well upto 1.3.2 but starts to fail from v1.4.0.

with Jquery 1.4.0 the page does not display anything. i get an error

Result of expression 'original_loadPage.defaults' [undefined] is not an object. at jqmobile-patch.js:106

anyone has idea what the file jqmobile-patch.js in rhomobile suite used for?

Answer (score 0):

Are you updating the jQuery library to a version compatible with jQueryMobile v1.4.5?

on top of this, in a RhoMobile scafolded project you get a JavaScript file that customise jQueryMobile:

`/public/js/jqmobile-patch.js`

You should try your application without this library (update accordingly layout.erb in your app) and see what is the behaviour.